# Calling function and update view from input

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code. I also have a function called calculateAge(birthdate) that I am using to update the age. What I can't figure out how to do is to call this function from the input when the person is done updating the birthdate input and in turns updates the age. Any help would be great.

Thanks,

```
<fieldset ng-model="mySeat.seat" class="col-xs-12 session-registrant" ng-repeat="seat in seats | filter:cartPerf.perf_no">

<div class="session-registrant-field field-date" ng-if="mySeat.seat.ask_birthdate == 'Y'">
                <label for="birthdate-{{$ + cartPerf.perf_no + "mySeat.seat.customer_no}}">
                    {{bdayLbl}}

                    <span class="error-msg" ng-show="registrantForm.$submitted || registrantForm['birthdate-' + cartPerf.perf_no + mySeat.seat.customer_no].$touched">
                        <span ng-show="registrantForm['birthdate-' + cartPerf.perf_no + mySeat.seat.customer_no].$error.required">(Required)</span>
                        <span ng-show="registrantForm['birthdate-' + cartPerf.perf_no + mySeat.seat.customer_no].$error.date">(Invalid birthdate)</span>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <div ng-bind="mySeat.seat.age"></div>
                <input 
                       type="date" 
                       name="birthdate-{{$ + cartPerf.perf_no + mySeat.seat.customer_no}}" 
                       id="" 
                       value="{{mySeat.seat.birthdate | formatDate: mySeat.seat.birthdate:'yyyy-MM-dd' || ''}}" 
                       ng-model="mySeat.seat.birthdate" 
                       ng-required="mySeat.seat.bdatereq == 'Y'">
            </div>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ngChange` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) on the `<input>` to perform actions after the value of the input has changed:

```
// Pretend this is your controller
function mySeat() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.seat = {
    // Whatever your seat property looks like
  };
  vm.calculateAge = function() {
    // Calculate the seat's age based on the current value of `birthdate`
    vm.seat.age = vm._someAgeCalcFun(vm.seat.birthdate);
  };
}
```

Then, in your HTML, add `ng-change` to your `<input>`:

```
<input 
  type="date" 
  name="birthdate-{{$ + cartPerf.perf_no + mySeat.seat.customer_no}}" 
  id="" 
  value="{{mySeat.seat.birthdate | formatDate: mySeat.seat.birthdate:'yyyy-MM-dd' || ''}}" 
  ng-model="mySeat.seat.birthdate" 
  ng-required="mySeat.seat.bdatereq == 'Y'"
  ng-change="mySeat.calculateAge()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change` to call the function when the input changes.

```
<input 
    type="date" 
    name="birthdate-{{$ + cartPerf.perf_no + mySeat.seat.customer_no}}" 
    id="" 
    value="{{mySeat.seat.birthdate | formatDate: mySeat.seat.birthdate:'yyyy-MM-dd' || ''}}" 
    ng-model="mySeat.seat.birthdate" 
    ng-required="mySeat.seat.bdatereq == 'Y'"
    ng-change="calculateAge()">
```